# Cannot determine project or target for command. Angular+Electron

Tags: angular, twitter-bootstrap, electron

I'm currently trying to run my angular project as an app using electron. I created a script in the package.json adding this line

```
"electron": "electron ."
```

after having build the app using the command

```
ng build myapp --prod
```

when I run the command:

```
ng run electron
```

I'm receiving the following error:

```
Cannot determine project or target for command.
Error: Cannot determine project or target for command.
at RunCommand.initialize (C:\Users\ ....\myapp\node_modules\@angular\cli\models\architect-command.js:37:23)
at <anonymous>
at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:188:7)
at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:695:11)
at startup (bootstrap_node.js:191:16)
at bootstrap_node.js:612:3
```

I tried to update the cli, the angular core and the bootstrap packages but nothing seems to be working.
When installing boostrap I ran the command:

```
npm install --save bootstrap@3
```

and after that I added to the angular.json file, under style the line:

```
"./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
```

Everything is working correctly when i run ng serve it seems somehow related to electron. Can anyone please help me?
Thanks

Comment: You can't start electron with `ng` command, You should get reference from here https://alligator.io/angular/electron/

Comment: Hi Mayank, thanks for answering. I know, that's why I created the script in the package.json file. what I'm running is actually that script (the name might sound confusing, sorry for that). Since the link you shared mentions it, I forgot to say that i manually changed in the index.html file the base href url to "./"